# Error SQL syntax multiple tables from different server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The sql syntax is following:

```
select 
    a.secCode, b.[Haircut (%)], c.[Absolute IDR (Miliar)] 
from 
    openquery(PDC_MYAPPS, 'select secCode from mii.secReq') a
left join 
    (select * from RC_Saham) b on a.secCode = b.kode 
left join 
    (select * from Absolute_IDR) c on b.kode = c.[Kode Saham]
where 
    b.[Haircut (%)] is not null 

union

select * 
from openquery(MANTARAY, 'select b.code_ic, a.PERC_HRCT 
                          from cminstruments a, instrument_codes b
                          where a.ID_CMI_CAPCO = b.INS_ID_INS_CAPCO')
where  
    code_Ic in (select a.secCode 
                from openquery(PDC_MYAPPS, 'select secCode 
                                            from mii.secReq') a 
                left join  
                   (select * from RC_Saham) b on a.secCode = b.kode 
                left join 
                   (select * from Absolute_IDR) c on b.kode = c.[Kode Saham]
                where b.[Haircut (%)] is null)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Any ideas how to solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message itself saying that, **equal number of expressions in their target lists.**

Try something like this,

```
SELECT a.secCode
      ,b.[Haircut (%)]
      ,c.[Absolute IDR (Miliar)]
FROM   OPENQUERY(PDC_MYAPPS ,'select secCode from mii.secReq')a
       LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT *
                FROM   RC_Saham
            )b
            ON  a.secCode = b.kode
       LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT *
                FROM   Absolute_IDR
            )c
            ON  b.kode = c.[Kode Saham]
WHERE  b.[Haircut (%)] IS NOT NULL 
UNION
SELECT a.secCode
      ,b.[Haircut (%)]
      ,c.[Absolute IDR (Miliar)]
FROM   OPENQUERY(
           MANTARAY
          ,
           'select b.code_ic, a.PERC_HRCT from cminstruments a, instrument_codes b
    where a.ID_CMI_CAPCO = b.INS_ID_INS_CAPCO'
       )
WHERE  code_Ic IN (SELECT a.secCode
                   FROM   OPENQUERY(PDC_MYAPPS ,'select secCode from mii.secReq')
                          a
                          LEFT JOIN (
                                   SELECT *
                                   FROM   RC_Saham
                               )b
                               ON  a.secCode = b.kode
                          LEFT JOIN (
                                   SELECT *
                                   FROM   Absolute_IDR
                               )c
                               ON  b.kode = c.[Kode Saham]
                   WHERE  b.[Haircut (%)] IS NULL)
```

Comment: still not working. I got this error:


Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "a.secCode" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "b.Haircut (%)" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "c.Absolute IDR (Miliar)" could not be bound.

Comment: check which columns you want to fetch from second union query.